# Why does my JSON.parse not work?

Tags: javascript, json

I make an array object in php then use json_encode to encode it, then echo it in javascript JSON.parse. I recive an error saying "VM1770:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token    in JSON at position 422
    at JSON.parse ()
    at LabOne.php:19"

Here is my JSON.parse line

```
var JSarray = JSON.parse( '[{"name":"Carlisle Community Centre & Arena","address":"1496 Centre Road","city":" Carlisle ","phone":"905-689-7283 ","latitude":"43.3966832","longitude":"-79.9813271"},{"name":"Chedoke Twin Pad Arena","address":"91 Chedmac Dr.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-2429 ","latitude":"43.2386207","longitude":"-79.9208443"},{"name":"Coronation Arena and Pool","address":"81 Macklin St. North","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-3109 \t","latitude":"43.2646431","longitude":"-79.8963275"},{"name":"Eastwood Arena","address":"111 Burlington St. East","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-3152 ","latitude":"43.2724438","longitude":"-79.8561951"},{"name":"Glanbrook Arena & Auditorium","address":"4300 Binbrook Road","city":" Binbrook ","phone":"\t905-692-9331 ","latitude":"43.1299662","longitude":"-79.8386732"},{"name":"Inch Park Arena & Pool","address":"400 Queensdale Ave.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-4922 ","latitude":"43.2374030","longitude":"-79.8591217"},{"name":"Lawfield Arena","address":"150 Folkstone Ave.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-4923 ","latitude":"43.2150052","longitude":"-79.8510790"},{"name":"Market Street (J.L. Grightmire) Arena","address":"35 Market St. South","city":" Dundas ","phone":"905-540-6678 ","latitude":"43.2660272","longitude":"-79.9635777"},{"name":"Mohawk 4 Ice Centre","address":"710 Mountain Brow Blvd.","city":" Hamilton \t","phone":"\t905-318-5111 ","latitude":"43.2094632","longitude":"-79.8171705"},{"name":"Morgan Firestone Arena","address":"385 Jerseyville Road West","city":" Ancaster ","phone":"\t905-546-3769 ","latitude":"43.2179937","longitude":"-80.0075459"},{"name":"Mountain (Dave Andreychuk) Arena","address":"25 Hester St.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-4938 ","latitude":"43.2255668","longitude":"-79.8809353"},{"name":"North Wentworth Twin-Pad Arena","address":"27 Hwy 5","city":" Flamborough ","phone":"\t905-689-6666 \t","latitude":"43.3128542","longitude":"-79.9222993"},{"name":"Olympic Arena","address":"70 Olympic Dr.","city":" Dundas ","phone":"\t905-540-6686 ","latitude":"43.2728720","longitude":"-79.9342542"},{"name":"Parkdale (Pat Quinn) Arena and Pool","address":"1770 Main St. East","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-4785 ","latitude":"43.2365765","longitude":"-79.7937876"},{"name":"Rosedale Arena and Pool","address":"100 Greenhill Ave.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-4805 ","latitude":"43.2215920","longitude":"-79.8144628"},{"name":"Saltfleet Arena","address":"24 Sherwood Park Road","city":" Stoney Creek ","phone":"\t905-643-3883 ","latitude":"43.2179779","longitude":"-79.7048414"},{"name":"Scott Park Arena","address":"876 Cannon St. East","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-4919 ","latitude":"43.2502045","longitude":"-79.8304338"},{"name":"Spring Valley Arena","address":"29 Orchard Dr.","city":" Ancaster","phone":"905-648-4404 ","latitude":"43.2169996","longitude":"-79.9981245"},{"name":"Stoney Creek Arena","address":"37 King St. West","city":" Stoney Creek ","phone":"\t905-662-2426 ","latitude":"43.2165957","longitude":"-79.7640822"},{"name":"Valley Park Arena & Rec Centre","address":"970 Paramount Dr.","city":" Stoney Creek ","phone":"905-573-3600 ","latitude":"43.1930991","longitude":"-79.7978639"}]' );
```

Appently it fails at the phone field of the element with the name field "Coronation Area and Pool".

I have checked the json string with JSONLint, but it says the json string is okay.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are writing this JSON string in your javascript code directly and that [escape characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) get converted before they pass the `parse` method.

If it weren't from a js string, but e.g from a *.json* file, or from an AJAX request, that would work.

But here `\t` gets converted to the *Tabulation*(U+0009) character from withing js directly.

To avoid this, you would have to

- double the backslashes on your escape characters when writing your js file (`\\t`),
- or to directly write the parsed object notation since it makes very little sense to write an JS object as a JSON string in a JS script. (`var JSarray = [{name: ...`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your use of `\t` in your phone numbers.

Removing all of these fixes the problem:

```js
var JSarray = JSON.parse('[{"name":"Carlisle Community Centre & Arena","address":"1496 Centre Road","city":" Carlisle ","phone":"905-689-7283 ","latitude":"43.3966832","longitude":"-79.9813271"},{"name":"Chedoke Twin Pad Arena","address":"91 Chedmac Dr.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-2429 ","latitude":"43.2386207","longitude":"-79.9208443"},{"name":"Coronation Arena and Pool","address":"81 Macklin St. North","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-3109 ","latitude":"43.2646431","longitude":"-79.8963275"},{"name":"Eastwood Arena","address":"111 Burlington St. East","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-3152 ","latitude":"43.2724438","longitude":"-79.8561951"},{"name":"Glanbrook Arena & Auditorium","address":"4300 Binbrook Road","city":" Binbrook ","phone":"905-692-9331 ","latitude":"43.1299662","longitude":"-79.8386732"},{"name":"Inch Park Arena & Pool","address":"400 Queensdale Ave.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-4922 ","latitude":"43.2374030","longitude":"-79.8591217"},{"name":"Lawfield Arena","address":"150 Folkstone Ave.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-4923 ","latitude":"43.2150052","longitude":"-79.8510790"},{"name":"Market Street (J.L. Grightmire) Arena","address":"35 Market St. South","city":" Dundas ","phone":"905-540-6678 ","latitude":"43.2660272","longitude":"-79.9635777"},{"name":"Mohawk 4 Ice Centre","address":"710 Mountain Brow Blvd.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-318-5111 ","latitude":"43.2094632","longitude":"-79.8171705"},{"name":"Morgan Firestone Arena","address":"385 Jerseyville Road West","city":" Ancaster ","phone":"905-546-3769 ","latitude":"43.2179937","longitude":"-80.0075459"},{"name":"Mountain (Dave Andreychuk) Arena","address":"25 Hester St.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-4938 ","latitude":"43.2255668","longitude":"-79.8809353"},{"name":"North Wentworth Twin-Pad Arena","address":"27 Hwy 5","city":" Flamborough ","phone":"905-689-6666 ","latitude":"43.3128542","longitude":"-79.9222993"},{"name":"Olympic Arena","address":"70 Olympic Dr.","city":" Dundas ","phone":"905-540-6686 ","latitude":"43.2728720","longitude":"-79.9342542"},{"name":"Parkdale (Pat Quinn) Arena and Pool","address":"1770 Main St. East","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-4785 ","latitude":"43.2365765","longitude":"-79.7937876"},{"name":"Rosedale Arena and Pool","address":"100 Greenhill Ave.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-4805 ","latitude":"43.2215920","longitude":"-79.8144628"},{"name":"Saltfleet Arena","address":"24 Sherwood Park Road","city":" Stoney Creek ","phone":"905-643-3883 ","latitude":"43.2179779","longitude":"-79.7048414"},{"name":"Scott Park Arena","address":"876 Cannon St. East","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-4919 ","latitude":"43.2502045","longitude":"-79.8304338"},{"name":"Spring Valley Arena","address":"29 Orchard Dr.","city":" Ancaster","phone":"905-648-4404 ","latitude":"43.2169996","longitude":"-79.9981245"},{"name":"Stoney Creek Arena","address":"37 King St. West","city":" Stoney Creek ","phone":"905-662-2426 ","latitude":"43.2165957","longitude":"-79.7640822"},{"name":"Valley Park Arena & Rec Centre","address":"970 Paramount Dr.","city":" Stoney Creek ","phone":"905-573-3600 ","latitude":"43.1930991","longitude":"-79.7978639"}]');
console.log(JSarray);
```

Assuming that you receive the JSON in a format where the `\t` instances are included, all you have to do is remove them with `.replace(/\t/g, '')`. Note that this will need to be done **before** parsing the JSON, and as such, I've separate out the steps for ease of clarity in the following example:

```js
var JSarray = '[{"name":"Carlisle Community Centre & Arena","address":"1496 Centre Road","city":" Carlisle ","phone":"905-689-7283 ","latitude":"43.3966832","longitude":"-79.9813271"},{"name":"Chedoke Twin Pad Arena","address":"91 Chedmac Dr.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-2429 ","latitude":"43.2386207","longitude":"-79.9208443"},{"name":"Coronation Arena and Pool","address":"81 Macklin St. North","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-3109 \t","latitude":"43.2646431","longitude":"-79.8963275"},{"name":"Eastwood Arena","address":"111 Burlington St. East","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-3152 ","latitude":"43.2724438","longitude":"-79.8561951"},{"name":"Glanbrook Arena & Auditorium","address":"4300 Binbrook Road","city":" Binbrook ","phone":"\t905-692-9331 ","latitude":"43.1299662","longitude":"-79.8386732"},{"name":"Inch Park Arena & Pool","address":"400 Queensdale Ave.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-4922 ","latitude":"43.2374030","longitude":"-79.8591217"},{"name":"Lawfield Arena","address":"150 Folkstone Ave.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"905-546-4923 ","latitude":"43.2150052","longitude":"-79.8510790"},{"name":"Market Street (J.L. Grightmire) Arena","address":"35 Market St. South","city":" Dundas ","phone":"905-540-6678 ","latitude":"43.2660272","longitude":"-79.9635777"},{"name":"Mohawk 4 Ice Centre","address":"710 Mountain Brow Blvd.","city":" Hamilton \t","phone":"\t905-318-5111 ","latitude":"43.2094632","longitude":"-79.8171705"},{"name":"Morgan Firestone Arena","address":"385 Jerseyville Road West","city":" Ancaster ","phone":"\t905-546-3769 ","latitude":"43.2179937","longitude":"-80.0075459"},{"name":"Mountain (Dave Andreychuk) Arena","address":"25 Hester St.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-4938 ","latitude":"43.2255668","longitude":"-79.8809353"},{"name":"North Wentworth Twin-Pad Arena","address":"27 Hwy 5","city":" Flamborough ","phone":"\t905-689-6666 \t","latitude":"43.3128542","longitude":"-79.9222993"},{"name":"Olympic Arena","address":"70 Olympic Dr.","city":" Dundas ","phone":"\t905-540-6686 ","latitude":"43.2728720","longitude":"-79.9342542"},{"name":"Parkdale (Pat Quinn) Arena and Pool","address":"1770 Main St. East","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-4785 ","latitude":"43.2365765","longitude":"-79.7937876"},{"name":"Rosedale Arena and Pool","address":"100 Greenhill Ave.","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-4805 ","latitude":"43.2215920","longitude":"-79.8144628"},{"name":"Saltfleet Arena","address":"24 Sherwood Park Road","city":" Stoney Creek ","phone":"\t905-643-3883 ","latitude":"43.2179779","longitude":"-79.7048414"},{"name":"Scott Park Arena","address":"876 Cannon St. East","city":" Hamilton ","phone":"\t905-546-4919 ","latitude":"43.2502045","longitude":"-79.8304338"},{"name":"Spring Valley Arena","address":"29 Orchard Dr.","city":" Ancaster","phone":"905-648-4404 ","latitude":"43.2169996","longitude":"-79.9981245"},{"name":"Stoney Creek Arena","address":"37 King St. West","city":" Stoney Creek ","phone":"\t905-662-2426 ","latitude":"43.2165957","longitude":"-79.7640822"},{"name":"Valley Park Arena & Rec Centre","address":"970 Paramount Dr.","city":" Stoney Creek ","phone":"905-573-3600 ","latitude":"43.1930991","longitude":"-79.7978639"}]';
JSarray = JSarray.replace(/\t/g, '');
Jsarray = JSON.parse(JSarray);
console.log(JSarray);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Do you know the preg_replace pattern for this? im using '/^[\\t]+$/' doent seem to work

Comment: Why are you trying to run `preg_replace()` on it? For starters, `preg_replace()` is PHP, when you are trying to parse in JavaScript. All you have to do is run a replace on the JavaScript side: `JSarray = JSarray.replace(/\t/g, '');`. I'll update my answer to cover this.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a solution that handles JSON where the `\t` instances are included.